# React FETCH fail from Spring boot api

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

I try and try but whatever I cant get the response into my react comp. The spring boot b/e working fine in browser or postman, tried each and every one of the @CrossOrigin in controller/ method/ both/ with origins="*", or 'localhost:3000', tried enabling CORS globally with WebMvcConfigurer bean on main app....even tried cors web properties in my properties file.....im fairly new to react so cud be hitting the goalposts there?

my react comp where i retrieve my users and pass them to another comp as props:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import UsersList from "../components/UsersList";

const Users = () => {
     const [users, updateUsers] = useState(null);
     useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/users',{
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                updateUsers(responseJson);//  responseJson._embedded  ???
    //the 'users' json payload is embedded in a parent "_embedded" key 
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.error(error);
            })

     }, []);
    return <UsersList items={users}/>;
    }
export default Users;
```

i cant seem to get anything back except a CORS error, but it feels like the response is empty, below is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@CrossOrigin(origins="*", allowedHeaders="*")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users;
    }
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header, it does not belong in your request. For that matter, neither does `Content-Type` belong in a GET request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)